# How convert JS Multiple Object string seperated by comma to js object or json?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a string like this

```
"{ identifier: '496006074',  amount: 349.90, currency: 'TRY', quantity: 1},{ identifier: '490703697',  amount: 1386.99, currency: 'TRY', quantity: 1},{ identifier: '401364283',  amount: 389.90, currency: 'TRY', quantity: 1}"
```

how can I convert this string into js object or json to access it by foreach.

Comment: Why do you have faulty JSON? Where are you getting it from? It is *usually* easier to make the source system produce correct JSON than pre-process it and try to guess the correct format.

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform your string to a `Json`able string first, then parse it.

```js
let x = "{ identifier: '496006074',  amount: 349.90, currency: 'TRY', quantity: 1},{ identifier: '490703697',  amount: 1386.99, currency: 'TRY', quantity: 1},{ identifier: '401364283',  amount: 389.90, currency: 'TRY', quantity: 1}"

let array = JSON.parse(`[${x.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*):/mg, '"$1":').replace(/[']/g, '"')}]`);

console.log(array);
```